# Tumblr ask box appearing where it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am writing a Tumblr theme and all went smoothly until I enabled the "ask box".

When I add the code for the ask box to my page, the box will appear on both my main page (where the posts are displayed), and also on my /ask page (which is the only page it should appear on).

I can't find anything on this issue in the tumblr documentation, and no themes I look at even have the tumblr ask box code in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ask box doesn't need to be hard coded. Tumblr creates an ask page for you at `'/ask'` by using the permalink page style for text posts. The only thing you need to worry about coding in your theme is the ask *link*.

Make sure you wrap the ask link in the appropriate blocks - `{block:AskEnabled}` and `{/block:AskEnabled}`.

(All of this is the same for submit pages too. Just a slightly different block which can be found in the [documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#navigation)).